# Parameters of a sigmoid regression in Python + scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, logistic-regression

I have a Python array containing **dates** representing the number of occurrences of a phenomenon in a particular year. This vector contains 200 different dates repeated a certain number of times each. Repetitions are the number of occurrences of the phenomenon. I managed to calculate and plot the cumulative sum with `matplotlib` with the following code snippet:

```
counts = arange(0, len(list_of_dates))
# Add the cumulative sum to the plot (list_of_dates contains repetitions)
plt.plot(list_of_dates, counts, linewidth=3.0)
```

[image: Cumulative sum (in blue) per date]

In blue, you can see the curve depicting the cumulative sum, in other colors the parameters I would like to obtain. However, **I need the mathematical representation** of the blue curve in order to obtain those parameters. I know that this type of curves can be adjusted **using logistic regression**, however, I do not understand how to do this in Python.

1. First I tried to use `LogisticRegression` from Scikit-learn, but then I realized they seem to be using this model for machine learning [classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html) (and other stuff alike), **which is not** what I want.
2. Then I thought I could go directly to the definition of logistic function and try to build it by myself. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106134/numpy-pure-functions-for-performance-caching) where it is recommended the use of `scipy.special.expit` to calculate the curve. It seems this function is already implemented, so I decided to use it. So I did this:

   `target_vector = dictionary.values()
    Y = expit(target_vector)
    plt.plot(list_of_dates, y, linewidth=3.0)`

I got a vector back with 209 elements (same as `target_vector`) that look like this: `[ 1. 0.98201379  0.95257413  0.73105858 ... 0.98201379  1. ]`. However, the graphical output looks like if a child had been scratching a paper, not as a nice sigmoid curve like in the picture.

I also checked other Stack Overflow threads ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308168/sigmoidal-regression-with-scipy-numpy-python-etc), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330438/another-sigmoidal-regression-equation-question)), but I guess the thing I need to do is just a toy example compared to them. I only need the math formula to calculate some quick and simple parameters.

Is there a way of doing this and getting the mathematical representation of the sigmoidal function?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Logistic Regression is indeed a classification problem. I think you are looking for a generalized linear model with a logit link function. I never did this in python, but `statsmodels` offers implementations for GLMs for a number of different link functions. I'm pretty sure you will find a model for logit regression there as well.

Comment: I have been checking the package you mention on the Logistic Regression category and to my (poor) knowledge, seems to be more oriented to "machine learning classification" problems, more than to "curve fitting" problem, which so far, I think is what I need: the mathematical description of the curve. Maybe I misused the terms on my initial post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66199/maximum-likelihood-curve-model-fitting-in-python) and the comments posted yesterday, I came up with the following code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize # Added this new line

# This is how I normalized the vector. "ydata" looked like this:
# original_ ydata = [ 1, 3, 8, 14, 12, 27, 33, 36, 87, 136, 77, 57, 32, 31, 28, 24, 12, 2 ]
# The curve was NOT fitting using this values, so I found a function in 
# scikit-learn that normalizes (multidim) arrays: [normalize][2]

# m = []
# m.append(original_ydata)
# ydata = normalize(m, norm='l2') * 10

# Why 10? This function is converting my original values in a range 
# going from [0.00014, ..., 0.002 ] or something similar. So "curve_fit" 
# couldn't find anything but a horizontal line crossing y = 1. 
# I tried multiplying by 5, 6, ..., 12, and I realized that 10 is 
# the maximum value that lets the maximum value of my array below 1.00, like 0.97599. 

# Length of both arrays is 209
# Y-axis data has been normalized BUT then multiplied by 10
ydata = array([  5.09124776e-04,   1.01824955e-03, ... , 9.75992196e-01])
xdata = array(range(0,len(ydata),1))

def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
    y = 1 / (1+ np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
    return y

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)

x = np.linspace(0, 250, 250)
y = sigmoid(x, *popt)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x,y, linewidth=3.0, label='fit')
plt.ylim(0, 1.25)
plt.legend(loc='best')

# This (m, b, C) parameters not sure on where they are... popt, pcov? 
# y = C * sigmoid(m*x + b)
```

This program creates the plot you can see below. As you can see it is a fair adjustment, but I guess if I change the definition of Y in sigmoid function, by adding a C multipliying the first 1, probably I would get a better adjustment. Still on that.

[image: Sigmoid curve fitting]

It seems normalizing data (as suggested by Ben Kuhn in comments) is a required step, otherwise the curve is not created. However, if your values are normalized to very low values (near to zero) the curve is not drawn either. So I multiplied the normalized vector per 10, to scale it to bigger units. Then the program simply found the curve. I can't explain why, as I am a total novice on this. Please, note that this is only my personal experience, I do not say this is a rule.

If I print `popt` and `pcov` I obtain:

```
#> print popt
[  8.56332788e+01   6.53678132e-02]

#> print pcov
[[  1.65450283e-01   1.27146184e-07]
 [  1.27146184e-07   2.34426866e-06]]
```

And the [documentation on curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) says those parameters contain the *"Optimal values for the parameters so that the sum of the squared error is minimized"* and the *covariance* of the previous parameter.

**Is any of those 6 values the parameters that characterize the sigmoid curve?** Because if so, then the question is very close to be solved! :-)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The parameters are in `popt`. You construct the curve with `y = sigmoid(x, *popt)`, which calls `sigmoid` those values for the last two parameters.

Comment: So the first one is the slope (x0) and the second one is the intercept (k)? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple reasons that the plot you mentioned might look bad.

The first is because `dictionary.values()` returns the values in un-sorted order. What happens if you do something like (untested because I don't have your dictionary):

```
target_pairs = sorted(dictionary.iteritems()) #should be a sorted list of (date, count)
target_vector = [count for (date, count) in target_pairs]
```

and look at the resulting `target_vector`? It should now be increasing.

Getting from there to a logistic function requires a bit more work: you need to normalize `target_vector` so that the values lie in [0, 1], then apply `scipy.special.logit` (which turns a sigmoid on [0, 1] into a straight line), and then you can find the line of best fit to that. Then you can recover the parameters of your logistic model:

```
y = C * sigmoid(m*x + b)
```

Where `m` and `b` are the slope and intercept from your linear regression on the transformed data and `C` is the thing you divided by when you normalized the data.

Comment: You pointed out a very important detail: order. Indeed I did not considered that, so I modified my code with your suggestion. I also didn't know it was required to normalize Y-axis data, but it makes a lot of sense, so I did it. However, it is not clear to me how to obtain the parameters of the logistic model (slope, intercept and this divisor number). I am updating in a new post my current situation. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok, you used `curve_fit` which was a different method than I was expecting, but might work better. The value of `popt` will be the array `[x0, k]` that makes `sigmoid(x[i], x0, k)` be as close as possible to `y[i]`--so those are the two parameters of the sigmoid curve.

(The standard sigmoid curve returns numbers in [0,1] though--so to recover your original data you need to multiply it by whatever you divided it by to normalize. WRT normalizing, the point is to scale your data so that the minimum is 0 and the maximum is 1--i.e., divide `y` by `y.max()`. Is that what you did?)

Comment: Ok, so I understand that x0 is the slope, and k is the intercept. And those 2 are the ones characterizing the curve that is best matching my data. Is this statement correct? :-) Regarding normalization, I added some lines of code so you can see how did I performed that operation. I felt a bit lazy (T_T) to start doing the optimization by myself, and I discovered sklearn.preprocessing.normalize function that apparently does the trick. So I did NOT divided intentionally, but I had to SCALE my values because they were too small for "curve_fit". What do you think? Does it make sense? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am trying to find the value of y(x) in a point. For this, I took the values returned in "popt" and put them in the function. Like this: y(100) = sigmoid(100, 8.56332788e+01, 6.53678132e-02). However, this is returning y(100) = 0.9974. Which is not true, according to the plot. Similarly, y(50) = 0.9375, which is not true either. Why results are shifted, but the curve looks good? Thanks